# How to create css grid with different count of items in different rows

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create responsive grid with CSS, which will have three items in the first row and two in second. Here's the design

[image]

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means a CSS expert, but heres my attempt at doing it:

```css
.item1 { grid-area: one; }
.item2 { grid-area: two; }
.item3 { grid-area: three; }
.item4 { grid-area: four; }
.item5 { grid-area: five; }
.space1 { grid-area: spaceleft; }
.space2 { grid-area: spaceright; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'one one two two three three'
    'spaceleft four four five five spaceright';
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid > div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1"><img src="https://placehold.jp/400x400.png"></div>  
  <div class="item2"><img src="https://placehold.jp/400x400.png"></div>
  <div class="item3"><img src="https://placehold.jp/400x400.png"></div>
  <div class="space1"></div>
  <div class="item4"><img src="https://placehold.jp/400x400.png"></div>
  <div class="item5"><img src="https://placehold.jp/400x400.png"></div>
  <div class="space2"></div>
</div>
```

It looks like this[image: first row has 3 items, second row has 2 items]

There's probably a thousand different ways to do this, but this is one way.
I hope you get some other responses as well.